# Google People API: reading "other contacts" with addresses

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, google-people-api

I need to read addresses of "other contacts". [Docs say](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/people_v1.otherContacts.html#list) that in order to do this, `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE` should be set. However, when doing it like this:

```
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('people', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
resource = service.otherContacts()

request = resource.list(
    readMask='names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,addresses',
    sources='READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE',
    pageSize=1000
)

request.execute()
```

... I am getting the following error: `Must request READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT`. Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leo\workspace\gapitest\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Leo\workspace\gapitest\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\workspace\gapitest\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 937, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://people.googleapis.com/v1/otherContacts?readMask=names%2CemailAddresses%2CphoneNumbers&sources=READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE&pageSize=1000&alt=json returned "Must request READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT". Details: "Must request READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**It seems that what you are seeing might be a bug.**

I have filed this issue on Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225806431) so feel free to star it and eventually add a comment, as any updates shall be posted there.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the proper channel to report this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list):

> Specifying `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE` without specifying `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT` is not permitted.

Setting both `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT` and `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE` should resolve this issue.